# Why does this python multiprocessing script slow down after a while?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

Building on the [script from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing), I have the following scenario: A folder containing 2500 large text files (~ 55Mb each), all tab delimited. Web logs, basically.

I need to md5 hash the second 'column' in each row of each file, saving the modified files elsewhere. The source files are on a mechanical disk and the destination files are on an SSD.

The script processes the first 25 (or so) files really quickly. It then slows WAY down. Based on the first 25 files, it should complete all of them in 2 minutes or so. However, based on the performance after that, it will take 15 minutes (or so) to complete them all.

It's running on a server with 32 Gb of RAM and task manager rarely shows over 6 Gb in use. I have it set to launch 6 processes, but the CPU usage on the cores is low, rarely going over 15%.

Why is this slowing down? Read/write issues to the disk? Garbage collector? Bad code? Any ideas about how to speed it up?

Here's the script

```
import os

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import hashlib

class ThreadRunner(threading.Thread):
    """ This class represents a single instance of a running thread"""
    def __init__(self, fileset, filedirectory):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.files_to_process = fileset
        self.filedir          = filedirectory

    def run(self):
        for current_file in self.files_to_process:

            # Open the current file as read only
            active_file_name = self.filedir + "/" + current_file
            output_file_name = "D:/hashed_data/" + "hashed_" + current_file

            active_file = open(active_file_name, "r")
            output_file = open(output_file_name, "ab+")

            for line in active_file:
                # Load the line, hash the username, save the line
                lineList = line.split("\t")

                if not lineList[1] == "-":
                    lineList[1] = hashlib.md5(lineList[1]).hexdigest()

                lineOut = '\t'.join(lineList)
                output_file.write(lineOut)

            # Always close files after you open them
            active_file.close()
            output_file.close()

            print "\nCompleted " + current_file

class ProcessRunner:
    """ This class represents a single instance of a running process """
    def runp(self, pid, numThreads, fileset, filedirectory):
        mythreads = []
        for tid in range(numThreads):
            th = ThreadRunner(fileset, filedirectory)
            mythreads.append(th) 
        for i in mythreads:
            i.start()
        for i in mythreads:
            i.join()

class ParallelExtractor:    
    def runInParallel(self, numProcesses, numThreads, filedirectory):
        myprocs = []
        prunner = ProcessRunner()

        # Store the file names from that directory in a list that we can iterate
        file_names = os.listdir(filedirectory)

        file_sets = []
        for i in range(numProcesses):
            file_sets.append([])

        for index, name in enumerate(file_names):
            num = index % numProcesses
            file_sets[num].append(name)


        for pid in range(numProcesses):
            pr = Process(target=prunner.runp, args=(pid, numThreads, file_sets[pid], filedirectory)) 
            myprocs.append(pr) 
        for i in myprocs:
            i.start()

        for i in myprocs:
            i.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    file_directory = "E:/original_data"

    processes = 6
    threads   = 1

    extractor = ParallelExtractor()
    extractor.runInParallel(numProcesses=processes, numThreads=threads, filedirectory=file_directory)
```

Comment: It's possible that you're getting a performance boost because the first files are cached in memory by the operating system, so no disk I/O happens. You can easily check this by rebooting the server and see if the processing slows down. If you can't reboot, you should fill the cache with something else, by reading enough files from the disk to fill the physical memory. If you have local access, you can simply listen closely for disk seeks. It's worth mentioning that performing hashing on files is most certainly bound by the disk, not CPU, so performing it in parallel is useless in the best case

Comment: In addition, if your source files are on a mechanical disk, it's probable that 6 processes reading from them at once will slow you down tremendously, especially on Windows where I/O scheduling is notoriously bad. What happens when you move your source files to a SSD?

Comment: Actually, if I/O scheduling is the issue (which is likely if your CPU usage stays low), you should get an increase in performance by lowering ``numProcesses`` to 1.

Comment: @Max Noel I believe the source files (actually, the compiled bytecode) would be read only once and kept both in disk cache and memory-mapped files (unless the bytecode was really, *really* big)

Comment: @goncalopp By "the source files" I mean his *input* files (the 55Mb logs), not the Python source code.

Comment: @MaxNoel Of course, that makes much more sense! I immediately thought of source code files

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I don't have room on the SSD to move all of the source files there and output there, too, but I'll try moving some of them and run a test. I'll also try lowering the number of processes to 1 to see what happens.

Comment: @MaxNoel Dropping the number of processes to 1 definitely speeds things up. I suppose this ultimately would be limited by how many read/write heads are on the hard drive?

Comment: Yup. As @goncalopp said, the bottleneck isn't, and never was, your CPU. It's the mechanical hard drive (which, when running multiple processes in parallel, is compounded by Windows's really bad I/O scheduling).

Comment: @MaxNoel Am I correct in assuming that the problem would go away if the source files were on an SSD? Or do the I/O problems carry over to SSDs?

Comment: @goncalopp If you want to write up your comment as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashing is a relatively simple task, and modern CPUs are very fast, compared to the speed of spinning disks. A quick-and-dirty benchmark on a i7  shows that it can hash about 450 MB/s using MD5, or 290 MB/s using SHA-1. Comparatively, spinning disk have a typical (sequencial raw read) speed of about 70-150 MB/s. This means that, even ignoring the overhead of the filesystem and eventual disk seeks, the CPU can hash a file about 3x faster than the disk can read it.

The performance boost you get on processing the first files probably happens because the first files are cached in memory by the operating system, so no disk I/O happens. This can be confirmed by either:

- rebooting the server, thus flushing the cache
- filling the cache with something else, by reading enough large files from the disk
- listening closely for the absence of disk seeks while processing the first files

Now, since the performance bottleneck for hashing files is the disk, performing the hashing in multiple processes or threads is useless, because they'll all use the same disk. As @Max Noel mentioned, it can actually *lower* performance, because you'll be reading several files in parallel, so your disk will have to seek between the files. The performance will also vary depending on the I/O scheduler of the operating system you're using, as he mentioned.

Now, if you're still generating data, you have some possible solutions:

- Use a faster disk, or a SSD, as @Max Noel suggested.
- Read from multiple disks - either in different filesystems or in a single filesystem over RAID
- Split the task over multiple machines (with a single or multiple disks each)

These solutions, however, are useless if all you want to do is hash those 2500 files and you already have them on a single disk. Reading them from the disk to other disks *and then* performing the hashing is *slower*, since you'll be reading the files twice, and you can hash as fast as you can read them.

Finally, based on @yaccz 's idea, I guess you could have avoided the trouble of writing a program to perform the hashing if you had installed cygwin binaries of `find`, `xargs` and `md5sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do things simple when one can make them complicated?

mount the drives via smbfs or whatnot on linux host and run

```
#! /bin/sh

SRC="" # FIXME
DST="" # FIXME

convert_line() {
    new_line=`echo $i | cut -f 1 -d "\t"`
    f2=`echo $i | cut -f 2 -d "\t"`
    frest=`echo $i | cut -f 1,2 --complement -d "\t"`

    if [ ! "x${f2}" = "-" ] ; then
        f2=`echo "${f2}" | md5sum | head -c-1`
        # might wanna throw in some memoization
    fi

    echo "${new_line}\t$f2\t${frest}"
}

convert_file() {
    for i in `cat $1`; do
        convert_line "${i}" >> $DST/hashed-$1
    done
}

for i in $SRC/*; do
    convert_file $i
done
```

not tested. might need polishing some rough edges.

Comment: Good idea, but the server is locked down and there's no way the admin would let me do that.