# Multiprocessing.pool.imap on a cluster gets slower and slower as the iteration goes on

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run my code on an HPC cluster, which needs to call some **function** 8000 times in every one of 100 iterations.

In the first couple of iterations, it runs quite well, about **4 minutes** per iteration. I don't know why it keeps getting slower with the iteration continuing for 4-5 hours, every iteration would cost **10+ minutes**.

I checked the status of the job, it says the CPU efficiency was about 5% and memory was utilized at about 4%.

Why is this slowing down? Is it about I/O scheduling? Or other issues?

I read the old question [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383114/why-does-this-python-multiprocessing-script-slow-down-after-a-while), and if my problem is also about I/O scheduling, do I have to rewrite the outer_program to keep everything in RAM? Or is there an easier way to solve this problem?

About the **function**, it uses `subprocess.run` to call an outer program and reads the file of the program's result, which would cost about 0.5 sec in one call.

```
def A_function(m:np.ndarray):
    model_tmp = m.reshape(-1)
        
    model_file = "."+ multiprocessing.current_process().name + ".rho"

    with open(model_file, 'r') as f:
        # read model from model_file
        ...
        
    data_file = "." + multiprocessing.current_process().name + ".dat"
    

    # maybe rewrite the outer_program to skip the read/write part? Although it may be a little difficult
    outer_program = subprocess.run(["outer_program", model_file, data_file],
                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                    check=True)
    # the outer_program would write its result into the data_file


    with open(data_file, 'r') as f:
        # read data from data_file
        ...

    return data
```

So I want to use `multiprocessing.Pool` with **64 processes** to do parallel computing on 1 node which has 96 cores with 384GB RAM.

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=64) as pool:
    ...
    ...
    # theta_p is a (8000,N_model) numpy.array
    theta_p_chunks = np.vsplit(theta_p, 8000)
    result = np.stack(list(pool.imap(A_function, theta_p_chunks, 1000)))
```

I also need `numpy` and `scipy.linalg` to deal with some big data array, so I use `threadpoolctl` to increase the thread number to 8 locally

```
with threadpool_limits(limits=8, user_api='blas'):
    x = scipy.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

with some export like`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` in my **sbatch** script:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS = 1
export MKL_NUM_THREADS = 1
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS = 1
export VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS = 1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS = 1
```