# Python Multithreading how to set 1 pool to run tasks as a queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to make one pool to run tasks which should follow the queue and the order.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def func(msg):
   for i in xrange(3):
      print msg
   time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    for i in xrange(10):
       msg = "hello %d" %(i)
       pool.apply_async(func, (msg, ))
    pool.close()

    time.sleep(50);
    print "Sub-process(es) done."
```

It can print something. However there are not come up one by one. It will be done all immediately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeError on windows trying python multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing)

Comment: Side-note: `time.sleep(50);` is a dumb way to do this. Just call `pool.join()` after `pool.close()` so you block until the process(es) are _actually_ done.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know I am just testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it runs at the different time. But it will show up at the same time.