# Python pathos error "ERROR:root:<class 'RuntimeError'>"

Tags: python, pathos

I am using Pathos for parallelism: https://pypi.org/project/pathos/
All good except when instantiating the Pool I get some annoying error messages.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
p = Pool().map    #<--This line spits out four lines to console:

"ERROR:root:<class 'RuntimeError'>" 

#(I have four CPUs, so I guess one each)
```

Seems everything is working fine. These four errors are just little annoying but it's not interfering with anything else.

Anyway I can silent these error messages from printing to console?

Comment: Which version of `pathos`, which version of `python`, which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `pathos` author.  It looks more like a `logging` module error.  I don't know your exact python version and whatnot but I expect something like this is the root cause:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.error(RuntimeError)
ERROR:root:<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>
```

No idea why you'd be seeing that from `pathos`.  However, if it's not spurious and you want to dig into it further, you should post an issue on the pathos GitHub page.

https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues

Comment: Thanks Mike, i been meaning to respond to this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike, 
The error goes away, after I added:

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__'
```

Before calling:

```
pool = Pool().imap
```

REF:
   [RuntimeError on windows trying python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing)