# How can I create just three threads or a fixed number of threads and distribute X of lists to them

Tags: python, multithreading, networking

Suppose that there is a method receiving data from somewhere. In this method we should create three threads or a fixed number of threads. Every piece of received data will be assigned to a thread.

In other words, if you will receive 10 lists of data (Note that the number of data items not fixed and can't be known), the first list will be assigned to the first thread, the second list to the second thread, third list to the third thread and the fourth list will start over and assign to the first thread or to any available thread and like so.

So the only number we know is the number of the threads that they will running in that method.

Note that the three threads should be running in the same time. Once a thread becomes available or finishes its task it will get the next data item and process it.

This is what I am doing now but if I have 30 lists of data, 30 threads will be created which is terrible.

```
threads = []
for ip in ip_list:
    for cmd in commands:
        th = threading.Thread(target=test_ssh_conn(ip,cmd), args=(ip,))  # args is a tuple with a single element
        th.start()
        threads.append(th)

for th in threads:
    th.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fixed number of threads and use a thread-safe global work queue to store tasks. While there are tasks, worker threads poll one and work on it. Once the work queue is empty, threads can re-join main.

Since Python's interpreter is [single-threaded](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), consider using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html). The API is the same, so it's easy to switch between the two according to need.

Here's a basic example using some mock data and a function stub to simulate :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty
from random import uniform
from time import sleep

def work():
    while 1:
        try:
            test_ssh_conn(*tasks.get(timeout=0.5))
        except Empty:
            break
            
    print("thread exiting")

def test_ssh_conn(ip, cmd):
    print("working on %s %d" % (ip, cmd))
    sleep(uniform(1.0, 2.0)) # pretend to do work
    print("done working on %s %d" % (ip, cmd))

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    thread_count = 3
    threads = []
    tasks = Queue()
    ip_list = ["172.16.0.0", "172.31.255.255", "192.168.0.0"]
    cmds = list(range(5))

    for ip in ip_list:
        for cmd in cmds:
            tasks.put((ip, cmd))
    
    for _ in range(thread_count):
        th = Process(target=work)
        threads.append(th)
        th.start()

    for th in threads:
        th.join()
```

Comment: I got a Run time error
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:
if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: Updated--[explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing).

Comment: Thank you, It works but It didn't do the functions in test_ssh_conn
@ggorlen

Comment: What do you mean? That's your function--I can't offer any code related to that since you haven't posted it, so I'm expecting you'll delete my stub function and mock data and use your own.

Comment: This is my code 1st Pic: 1drv.ms/u/s!As07BXc6FSobzgeL4I3N8JZy8xHd 2nd Pic: 1drv.ms/u/s!As07BXc6FSobzgjITjzXe8mw8piW @ggorlen

Comment: I tried your code too, it didn't print what in test_ssh_conn

Comment: What you're offering isn't something I can really act on. [This works fine](https://repl.it/repls/GiganticEnlightenedElement), so please be descriptive and explain exactly what is different between what your version does and mine.

Comment: I post the answer, it is your code but need to some editing @ggorlen

Comment: Please don't post non-working code snippets as answers. Use repl.it to post your code, illustrating exactly what isn't working.