# multiprocessing.Process() just stopped working

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I was teaching myself about multiptocessing in Python on Spyder and was working through some relatively simple examples when it suddenly stopped working. Going back to some simpler examples that had previously worked they now seemed to be not working as well. I can't think what I could have done to make them stop working. Below is my code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done Sleeping...')


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()


finish = time.perf_counter()


print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')
```

It just seems to run as if the middle part:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Is not there?

edit

The only output was

```
Finished in 0.64 second(s)
```

with no error message.

Comment: What does stopped working mean? Gives an error?

Comment: It just ran as if the multiprocessing code wasn't there outputting "Finished in 0.64 second(s)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the `error` and follow the instruction !

```
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Please run the below code:

```
import multiprocessing


def worker(num):
    """Returns the string of interest"""
    return "worker %d" % num


def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    results = pool.map(worker, range(10))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for result in results:
        # prints the result string in the main process
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Better protect your main function when you use multiprocessing
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks I never got any error it just finished like the multiprocessing code wasn't there saying "Finished in 0.64 second(s)"

Comment: @ChristopherEll are you running it via Windows ? if yes. so which `IDLE`. and please confirm if you run it as `python script.py`

Comment: Yes, I am running on windows on Spyder

Comment: @ChristopherEll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing

Comment: Thanks αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  I think I am still having trouble I have tried putting the if __name__ == '__main__' at various points in the program but still pretty much get the same results.

Comment: @ChristopherEll could you please confirm if you run the script as `python script.py` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202962/discussion-between--c-and-christopher-ell).