# Python3 multiprocessing Pool and Lock error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, locking, python-multiprocessing

i have have code similaire to what shown below, So please i want the proper solution to run this without errors, i got shared memory error and also open gui many times,

```
mainapp = ProcessFiles()
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
p.map(mainapp.getPdfInfo, Files_list)
p.close()

class ProcessFiles:

    def __init__():
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def getPdfInfo(file):
        #READ FILES DATA AND DO SOME STUFFS
        self.lock.aquere()
        #INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
        self.lock.release()
```

and this the error msg

```
 TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Connection objects
```

Alos tried with multiprocessing.Manager() and also got errors, Code shown below

```
mainapp = ProcessFiles()
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
p.map(mainapp.getPdfInfo, Files_list)
p.close()

class ProcessFiles:

    def __init__():
        m = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.lock = m.Lock()

    def getPdfInfo(file):
        #READ FILES DATA AND DO SOME STUFFS
        self.lock.acquire()
        #INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
        self.lock.release()
```

and thats the error msg

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
 exitcode = _main(fd)
 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 _check_not_importing_main()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in 
 _check_not_importing_main
 is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
 RuntimeError: 
     An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
     current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

     This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
     child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
     in the main module:

         if __name__ == '__main__':
             freeze_support()
             ...

     The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
     is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: Please describe what the errors are. Note that the spelling is [`lock.acquire()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects).

Comment: @KenY-N check it again i edited

Comment: @KenY-N problem is not in spelling

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError on windows trying python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing)