# Multiprocess Python: Working code of a tutorial doesn't work when I try it

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am watching the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso (shown at 8.18 min) about multiprocessing. I am running the code copied from there:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

start = time.perf_counter()


def do_something():

    print("sleeping 1 sec...")
    time.sleep(1)

    print("done sleeping...")


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

p1.start()
p2.start()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print("finished in " + str(round((finish-start),2))   + " seconds(s)")

os.system("pause")
```

But when I run it on my computer I have the following error message (but the same code works on the tutorial):

> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
>           current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
>           child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
>           in the main module:
>               if **name** == '**main**':
>                   freeze_support()
>                   ...
>           The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
>           is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing

Comment: you need a if __name__=='__main__': block where you call the multiprocessing

Comment: I don't understand why it works on the tutorial...

Comment: can it be because running it in a windows machine is different?

Comment: The code works fine in python3. You better try to join the new processes at the end with `p1.join(); 
p2.join()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. Finally it works.
So basically in windows it needs to be written in a slightly different way:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

start = time.perf_counter()


def do_something():

    print("sleeping 1 sec...")
    time.sleep(1)

    print("done sleeping...")

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print("finished in " + str(round((finish-start),2))   + " seconds(s)")

    os.system("pause")
```