# Run multiple functions parallelly in python

Tags: python, function

Ok so, I searched for this answer all over the internet but I am getting the answers which just run these functions one after the other

```
import time

def a():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("lmao")
def b():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("not so lmao huh")
```

I want "lmao" and "not so lmao" to be printed at the same time ( after 5 seconds)
The solutions which I saw all over the internet just printed "lmao" after 5 seconds of starting the program and "not so lmao huh" after 5 seconds of `a()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your functions parallel, then you may want to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

You can create some processes and execute your function in them.

For example:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.context import Process


def a():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("lmao")


def b():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("not so lmao huh")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1: Process = mp.Process(target=a)
    p2: Process = mp.Process(target=b)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

There are also such API for [coroutines and tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading). Maybe you will find them more convenient.

Comment: well it just gives an error
.................
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: @Chinar It looks like you are using windows and there it's mandatory to use `if __name__ ...`. For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing). I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Far as i understood your question you should  use threading for it. you can refer this guide [Threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).
If you need any clarification feel free to comment.

```
import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```

Comment: it is just printing "Error: unable to start thread"
and also can you please make a program with my functions