# Multiprocessing Processes killing instantly?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use Python `multiprocessing` module. Here is some example code

```
from multiprocessing import Process 
 
def foo(): 
    print("Hello" )
 
def foo2(): 
    print("Hello again" )
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('program started')
    global p1, p2
    p1 = Process(target=foo) 
    p2 = Process(target=foo2) 
    print(p1.is_alive())
    
    p1.start() 
    p2.start() 

    p1.join() 
    p2.join()
```

As you can see, `foo` and `foo2` are simple functions. I added the `__name__` guard after people suggested it: [Python multiprocessing processes instantly die after being started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143003/python-multiprocessing-processes-instantly-die-after-being-started).

When I run this on my computer, I get the following output:

```
program started
False
```

The code seems to be working, so can somebody please explain?

I am using MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a process is *alive* from the moment its `start` method is called. So it is normal that `is_alive` returns `False`.

Now, if you run a program from an IDE, that might have unintended side effects.
In case of problems, always run your script from the command-line first.

Answer (score -1):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!

Not sure why, (can somebody help me research this?), but it seems to be IDLE's fault:

I changed IDE's to VS Code, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Trying to run `multiprocessing` from a REPL or an IDE interpreter is usually a *bad* idea (it causes many of the same problems as not using the `__name__ == '__main__'` guard does, plus a whole bunch of new problems that are only semi-predictable), but the problem you're experiencing is almost certainly because you check `is_alive` before actually launching (calling `start` on) the `Process`.

Comment: IIRC, IDLE redirects STDOUT, so the child processes may be `print`ing to a different (invisible) console. Other IDE's have found various solutions to address this problem, but running the file directly from a terminal (without an IDE) should always work as expected. I use Spyder, and over time it has gotten better at handling stdout from multiprocessing, but that wasn't always the case.