# Python Multiprocessing workflow troubleshooting

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to run a data feed that gets data from a websocket on a process called `feed_process`. I wish to push that data to a database using a **separate process** `data_process` (hence the multiprocessing).

This is to not slow down my data feed (otherwise, the latency adds up and I get data lag).

I have a `queue = multiprocessing.Queue()` that I think I want to put data in from the `feed_process` and get data from, from the `data_process`

I have made a crude diagram:

[image: diagram]

How would I structure this program using multiprocessing? Is this the ideal way to think about this?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to write the code but I come across errors. Here is a snippet of the code related to multiprocessing:

```py
def ticker_function(data, time):
    # Send data to queue
    queue.put(data, block=False)

def worker(queue):
    while True:
        data = queue.get(block=False)
        if data is None:
            print("No data")

def start_feed():
    # Start collecting data from the websocket feed via f.run()
    f.run()

data_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
feed_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_feed)
data_process.start()
feed_process.start()
```

I receive errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/user/sandbox/live-pnl/main.py", line 113, in <module>
    data_process.start()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 288, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/user/sandbox/live-pnl/main.py", line 113, in <module>
    data_process.start()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 288, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 154, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
    raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Not sure which part has any mistakes. I understand now that my code may be IO bound and multiprocessing might not be the best way forward but wish to pursue anyway to learn.

Comment: If your operation is IO bound as it sounds like it is, you may want to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing. But your premise sounds reasonable

Comment: @Matt how would I know if my operation is IO bound?

Comment: Is there any heavy calculations or other computations being done on the data, or is it just waiting for data to be returned from the websocket

Comment: @Matt No, the part that slows it down is having to send it to the database right after receiving it

Comment: Yeah that's IO bound

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247936/discussion-between-matt-and-fvim).

Comment: This issue has been discussed about a zillion times. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing

Comment: @Vlad Thanks it works now, I saw that but assumed it wouldn't be the solution since I am not on windows (it seemed at first glance that was related to windows only)
If you wish to post an answer I can mark it as solved